# how MIX subtractions works with "packed" words

Tags: computer-science

Im reading the Knuth's book TAOCP. And im just learning a simple math operations with registers. And there is an example of subtraction operation:

```
rA before: - | 1234 | 0| 0| 9
Cell 1000: - | 2000 |  150| 0
SUB 1000    
rA after:  + | 766  | 149 | ?
```

i understand that -1234-(-2000) = 766
but how (0 | 0)  - 150  = 149 ??

and why 9 - 0 = ?

These are "packed" words. And maybe i need to read more about them. Or can anyone explain ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that in MIX the byte size is not fixed. In `| 2000 | 150| 0`, although we know that the (3:4) field contains 150 we don't know what the (3:3) and (4:4) fields are individually.
A 6-bit-per-byte computer sees the low end of the computation as
$$150\times 64 - 9 = 9591 = 149\times 64 + 55,$$so 149 is stored in the (3:4) field and 55 in the (5:5) field.
A 7-bit-per-byte computer sees the low end of the computation as
$$150\times 128 - 9 = 19191 = 149\times 128 + 119,$$ so 149 is stored in the (3:4) field and 119 in the (5:5) field.
Thus the (3:4) field is 149 both times but the (5:5) field may vary and so is shown as unknown.

Note also the the default F-code (0:5) is being used with the SUB instruction, so the whole word is being used, and that fact that there appear to be packed values involved doesn't alter that.